# MySQL - Search/SELECT which is ordered by relevance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table setup as follows:

```
 userid year  model  color  transmission  interiorcolor wheels
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   2005  Fiesta   Red   MT             Black        Stock
   2   2008  Monaro   Red   AT             Black        Stock
   3   2005  F-150S   Blue   AT            Black + Red  Stock
   4   2008  Fiesta   Green   MT           Black        Stock
```

Now I am building an SQL search (no standard build in full text search), and I want to results to be somewhat relevant.

What i mean is that for example if someone types in "2008 Fiesta", right now with a basic query the results come out in this order

id #1, id #2, id #4

But really I would like #4 to be on the top of the search in that case because it matches my search on two fields instead of just one field.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crude but it should work for you:

```
SELECT id, SUM(Relevance) as SearchRelevance
FROM(
SELECT id, 1 as Relevance
FROM cars
WHERE year = 2008
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 1 as Relevance
FROM cars
WHERE model='Fiesta') AS t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY SUM(Relevance) DESC
```

Basically it has a search for each criteria, UNIONs them all together and then groups them and orders by the SUM of relevance (where you get one point per matching item).

Comment: But now you're assuming that model and year are separated, which isn't the case if it is a full-text search.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom - According to the OP, there is "no standard build in full text search".  I'm assuming the OP will break up the parts of the string somehow.  This is where the PHP code will come in probably.

Comment: Wow that works very well!  Do you know how I could have it expanded so it doesnt just run through the year and model fields, but all of my fields (and the real list of fields is actually longer then what I posted here), also the keywords would be one long entry, the search text woud be "2008 red Fiesta" for example.  In your sql, the relevant keywords are already assigned.  Anyways to keep it more general for a real world search request?  thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at using Lucene (or SOLR on top of Lucene), instead of relying on MySQL for something like this. You can still store your real data in MySQL. The general setup I use is SOLR/Lucene to do full text/relevance searches to get the ids of the entities I'm interested in, then hit MySQL to grab the actual data for those entities. Using SOLR/Lucene gives you a full text search and adds a lot more power in the ways you can search/order the data, plus it gives things like stemming and the like.

Comment: It also depends on the size of the data set. For small data sets MySQL could do the searching without serious problems. For large amounts of data there are better options such as Lucene or Xapian.

Comment: True enough. I threw Lucene out as an option because he mentioned full text search while asking about relevancy. Those two together point me towards an actual search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `select` statement is like:

```
LIKE %2008 Fiesta%
```

Try taking the last `%`, it will work

Comment: And if you would use the search "Fiesta 2008" the result would be empty?